# Logo size changed in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode7

I'm getting this warning saying "**Frame for the logo will be different at run time**". After running in the simulator, the logo size will be enlarged automatically. It requires me to change the logo size. But no matter I fix it myself or ignore it, the logo size will be changed ultimately.

**(In the Attributes column, I set the mode to "Aspect Fit" for the logo image, could this be the reason?)**

Anyone knows how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check your Constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your frames in your storyboard. Click on the `Resolve Auto Layout Issues button` in the bottom right corner (look at the icon at the bottom of the image). Then click on `Update Frames`. You can either select the view itself or update all of the views.

[image]

Comment: After using the Update Frames, the logo will still be enlarged.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are saying. Could you please clarify? Thanks

Comment: I have tried your method, but after I run it again, the logo size will still be changed to a bigger one.

Comment: Isn't that what you were trying? My solution shows how to fix the error you are receiving. What you are talking about seems to be an error within the constraints.